# pandas vectorization optimization-python

Tags: python, pandas

I have data from a table in a data warehouse and I have to apply and a iteration over all the data and per each row I have to look into the same table and get the historical data based on month for the same id. Once I have the historical data I want to iterate over it to extract the average in each iteration.

the data and code sample can be found here: https://github.com/jordi-crespo/optimise-data-tranformation-in-python/blob/master/stackover/stackoverflow.py

I have to do it in Python and I have thought in do it with pandas but it takes some time in do everything:

1. I read the data from a json and the output of the first dataframe is this:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

2. I do an iteration over the table and I get the historical data per each row and after that I do some operations :

> ```
> df = pd.read('df.csv')
> df_past = pd.read('df_past_csv')
>
> def getdataframe(df,date,id):
>     #transform date into datetime object
>     datetime_object = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d')
>     #transform string column to datetime column
>     df['date']= pd.to_datetime(df['date']) 
>     #getting month from 12 previous month
>     previous12thmonth = datetime_object - relativedelta(months=+12)
>     #filter per an_name
>     #filter per siteid
>     df = df[df['id']==id]
>     #filtering
>     filtered_dataframe = df[
>     (df['date']>= pd.Timestamp(previous12thmonth)) ]
>     return filtered_dataframe
>
> def average12months(df_past):
>
>     for index, past in df_past.iterrows():       
>
>         avergaeCancelRatePreviousMonths = df_past['price'][:index].mean() if index != 0 else 10
>         history_considered_months_df.loc[index, 'price'] =  price
>         average = df_past['price'].mean()
>     return average, df_past
>
> for index, rows in df.iterrows():
>     df_past = getdataframe(df_past,rows['date']
>                                         ,rows['id']
>     average,df_past = average12months(df_past)
> ```

I have been reading that for speed up the operation I can use vectorization over pandas series:
https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6

How could I change the interrows loop for a vectorization over a series?

Comment: How large are these files? I'm not saying it's impossible, but vectorization basically always takes at least linear time (O(n)). If you have some large files, there isn't a whole lot you can do aside from threading it.

Comment: For other people on here... his data's about 9000 rows, and ~1.2MB for each file, based on his github content in the link above.

Comment: It looks like you're doing a search for the row in `df_past` for each row in your main `df`. Try restructuring the code so that instead of searching, you might passively align the rows, like with a `zip()`

Comment: I don't think you have to zip. You're looking at two tables, that you need to join, and then do some filter/calculation on. To merge, just run: merged_df = pd.merge(df, past_df, on="id"). I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do for every row in the main df - I would have proposed a solution otherwise.

Comment: Well theoretically the historical data is in the same dataframe, but I have put it as a two different dataframes. I want to take  each line and see if there is historical data for the same id. I just want to know if I can avoit to do an interrows and do it with vectorization.